# VS 2010 express. Syntax error : 'do'

Tags: visual-c++

I am working with code that was written in VS 6.0. I am able to open the project in VS 2010 express. But when I compile it, it gives me the odd errors:

[image]

here the code that it's pointing to

```
#define AFX_CRT_ERRORCHECK(expr) do { expr; } while (0)

#if _SECURE_ATL

    #ifdef _AFX
    #define ATLMFC_CRT_ERRORCHECK(expr) AFX_CRT_ERRORCHECK(expr)
    #else
    #define ATLMFC_CRT_ERRORCHECK(expr) ATL_CRT_ERRORCHECK(expr)
    #endif
...
inline errno_t __cdecl strncpy_s(__out_ecount(_SizeInChars) char *_Dest, __in size_t _SizeInChars, __in_z const char *_Source, __in size_t _Count)
{
    return ATLMFC_CRT_ERRORCHECK(::strncpy_s(_Dest, _SizeInChars, _Source,_Count)); 
}

inline errno_t __cdecl wcsncpy_s(__out_ecount(_SizeInChars) wchar_t *_Dest, __in size_t _SizeInChars, __in_z const wchar_t *_Source, __in size_t _Count)
{
    return ATLMFC_CRT_ERRORCHECK(::wcsncpy_s(_Dest, _SizeInChars, _Source,_Count)); 
}

inline errno_t __cdecl tcsncpy_s(__out_ecount(_SizeInChars) TCHAR *_Dest, __in size_t _SizeInChars, __in_z const TCHAR *_Source, __in size_t _Count)
{
#ifndef _ATL_MIN_CRT
    return ATLMFC_CRT_ERRORCHECK(::_tcsncpy_s(_Dest, _SizeInChars, _Source,_Count));    
#else
#ifdef UNICODE
    return ATLMFC_CRT_ERRORCHECK(::wcsncpy_s(_Dest, _SizeInChars, _Source,_Count)); 
#else
    return ATLMFC_CRT_ERRORCHECK(::strncpy_s(_Dest, _SizeInChars, _Source,_Count)); 
#endif
#endif
}
```

Comment: You can't return a value from that the result of that macro.

Comment: So issue in this line: #define AFX_CRT_ERRORCHECK(expr) do { expr; } while (0)? Or in the function definition?

Comment: IIRC, there is a way to disable the deprecated 'insecure' stuff. I suggest you use that for now.

Comment: Can you point to some link with additional info?

Comment: Speaking for memory, it was some `#define`. Pretty sure MSDN and Google can help out here, but perhaps someone can provide you the answer.